Error when trying to Rename files using Excel VBA "Name" function
I am trying to write a script that will rename my files using Excel VBA (on a Mac - which I think is important with its file access granting requirement), and getting an "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument Error" when trying to execute the Name function.
I reduced it to this tester code.  Can anyone tell me what my problem is?
Sub RenameTester()

    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim originalFileName As String
    Dim newFileName As String
    Dim oldFilePath As String
    Dim newFilePath As String
    Dim AccessGranted As Boolean

        folderPath = "/Users/sparky/Desktop/"
        originalFileName = "OLD_NAME_1.jpg"
        newFileName = "FILE_RENAMED_1.jpg"
        oldFilePath = folderPath & originalFileName
        newFilePath = folderPath & newFileName
        MsgBox "Old: " & oldFilePath & " new: " & newFilePath. 'this all looks correct

        If Dir(oldFilePath) <> "" Then  ' Checks if the file exists
            FileArray = Array(oldFilePath)
            AccessGranted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(FileArray)
            MsgBox AccessGranted    'this returns true
            Name oldFilePath As newFilePath  'this is where the error occurs
        Else
            MsgBox "File not found: " & oldFilePath & ". Check your path and prefix"
        End If

I expected it to execute with no errors.  I checked it with multiple files and file names and paths. Even though the file exists and the GrantAccesstoMultipleFiles() function returns "True" I still get a pop-up asking me to grant access to the file, and even when I do grant access, I still get an "Invalid Procedure Call" error.

When you step through line-by-line (F8) does the macro open the file? I may take issue with renaming a file that's open. I've also encountered an issue where another user had the file open and it'd produce an error. The syntax of your Name line seems to be correct, but your error is saying a filename is not valid.

Thanks guys -- I ddi confirm that the file is not open (nor gets opened in the code that I can see anywhere).  Also not sure why the GrantMultipleFilesAccess() function appears to not do anything (given I get the dialog box to grant access every time I switch up a file name). Wondering if these two problems could be related?

I reduced it to this basic code and I still get that same error. Starting to think the Name function doesn't work on my computer.
Sub RenameTester4()
Dim oldFilePath As String
Dim newFilePath As String
oldFilePath = "/Users/sparky/desktop/OLD_NAME_1.jpg"
newFilePath = "/Users/sparky/desktop/FILE_RENAMED_1.jpg"
If Dir(oldFilePath) <> "" Then  ' Checks if the file exists
Name oldFilePath As newFilePath
End If
End Sub

I discovered the problem!!!  I am coding on my laptop which has all files stored in iCloud.  The Name function does not work properly when the files are not stored locally.  I had to hack a folder on the laptop hard drive itself and the function worked on files stored there.
